# Postgres Output id of dup rows between 2 tables

Tags: json, postgresql, duplicates

I have 2 tables. a master table and a master_staging table. I want to know which rows in the master_staging table also appear in the master table. bellow is the structure of master_staging

```
--------------+------------------------+-------
 id           | integer                |
 firstname    | character varying(255) |
 lastname     | character varying(255) |
 email        | text                   |
 address      | character varying(255) |
 country      | character varying(255) |
 phones       | json                   |
 twitters     | json                   |
 linkedin     | character varying(255) |
 urls         | json                   |
 source       | character varying(255) |
 notes        | json                   |
 conflict_id  | integer                | **************************
 businessname | character varying(255) |
 warnings     | json                   | **************************
 has_warning  | boolean                | **************************
 deleted      | boolean                | **************************
```

The structure of the master table is the exact same except it does not contain the columns with `'**************************'` in the third column of the above table.

One solution is to loop over all rows in the master_staging table and query the master table for rows which have the same firstname, lastname, email and from there 'manually' check if all other fields are identical.

I am hoping there is a more elegant solution which will allow me to make one run one sql statement which returns the ids of all rows in master_staging which have duplicates in master. The main problem that is stumping me is I'm not sure how to do deep json equality checks?

Comment: What makes a record in your table unique?

Comment: both tables have the id property which is unique for each table

Comment: `select ms.id from master_staging ms where exists (select * from master m where m.firstname = ms.firstname and m.lastname = ms.lastname and m.email = ms.email);`

Comment: So for the json fields would i do m.phones = ms.phones or cast(m.phones AS text) = cast(ms.phones AS text)? what would be the difference between the 2 syntax's?

Comment: In your question you did not mention "phones" to be a discrimatory field. Please stick to your question. My comment is correct. The answer you ticked is not (it will report duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can JOIN two tables on whatever fields make a record unique. For example,

```
Select M.id
From master M, master_staging MS
Where M.email= MS.email
and M.firstName = MS.firstName
and M.lastName = MS.lastName
```